# How to change the base_url in magento.,because my site were gone after i'm changing that on my magento admin

Tags: sql, url, magento, base-url

How to change the base_url in Magento, because my site were gone after i changed that on my magento admin settings... Now i got 404 error on that url, the admin and frontend won't open...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

execute the following query in mysql (via phpmyadmin or command line) to see what the current values are:

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%base%url%';
```

and then update accordingly

```
update core_config_data set value = 'http://myhostname/js/' where path = 'web/unsecure/base_js_url';
```

Comment: And then delete the contents of the `var/cache/` directory.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = replace(`value`, 'https://www.oldname.com/', 'https://www.newname.com/') WHERE `value` LIKE '%https://www.oldname.com/%';
```

Answer (score 2):

step 1: `mysql -u root -p` press <kbd>enter</kbd>
step 2: Enter your database password 
step 3:`select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';`
step 4:`select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/secure/base_url';`
step 5:`update core_config_data set value = 'https://domain.com/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';`
step 6:`update core_config_data set value = 'http://domain.com/' where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';`
step 7: `exit;` press <kbd>enter</kbd>
step 8: clear session and cache
step 9: `/etc/init.d/mysql start`
step 10: `sudo service apache2 restart`