# Changed admin url, and now cannot access Magento login page

Tags: magento, authentication, admin

I tried to change the admin url of magento. As per the basic settings, it was located on `www.domain.com/admin`
I tried to change that and now I can't even access the login page. When I enter the new word that I replaced with "**admin**", I am taken to a login page which just appears like a basic html page with a box for username and password, and when I login I'm taken to the homepage of the website.

I also noticed that the word has started to appear twice in the url of backend such as if the correct address is to be:

```
www.domain.com/index.php/newadminword/system_config/index/key/0ddf3e37ef9a494c10afe626dee8efc7/
```

but when I login by that basic html page, the url becomes:

```
www.domain.com/newadminword/index.php/newadminword/system_config/index/key/0ddf3e37ef9a494c10afe626dee8efc7/
```

I removed the first 'newadminword' from the url and then I'm being led to the magento admin area, but here as well, the page is again basic html. The following link is a pic of how my magento dashboard looks now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qnva.jpg

Can anybody help me with this? I'm not so good at programming so please try to keep the instructions as simple as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Do not use web admin panel to change the admin url
Read this :
https://www.properhost.com/members/knowledgebase/15/How-to-change-the-Magento-Admin-URL-or-Path.html

Here is a similar answer you may follow
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202950/magendo-admin-url-not-working-404-after-changing-it-cant-go-back/7211998#7211998

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202950/magendo-admin-url-not-working-404-after-changing-it-cant-go-back