# Magento Admin Panel URL change not taking effect.

Tags: magento, caching

I am attempting to update the admin panel url.

I edited `app/etc/local.xml` and changed the following line to the desired name:

```
<frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
```

I then went to my Magento root and cleared the cache by running rm `-rf var/cache/*`

This exact process worked beautifully when I first tested on my remote staging server, it updated to the new URL immediately. However, there was absolutely no change when I attempted it on my live site. The admin panel still showed up when I visited www.mysite.com/admin.

I had a short window of time when the traffic to our website is low and nobody is actively using the admin panel, so I changed the name back to admin and cleared the cache again after my change did not take effect.

Any ideas what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here.

http://www.pixlpitch.com/3-ways-to-change-magento-admin-path/

I personally used step 3

> another way is to change from the admin itself.Goto System→Config→Admin→Admin Base Url→Use Custom Admin Path, set yes. Set new admin path in Custom admin path text field and save.

Comment: I saw that as an option during my research, but felt a little nervous about messing up a setting inside the admin panel that controls the admin panel, since I am not comfortable enough with modifying database files to get it going again. 

I don't recall where I read it, but I got the impression that sometimes the internal setting is a little buggy sometimes?

Comment: It's very simple, you just do what it says there. And if and I say IF you by any chance mess up editing the php is very easy.

Comment: And then look up the fix here when it blows up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202950/magendo-admin-url-not-working-404-after-changing-it-cant-go-back The System Config setting is notorious for locking you out of the backend.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion and will attempt it if nobody is able to help me figure out why the way I attempted it did not work on my live server, but did work on my testing server.